# i executed a hadoop mapreduce program successfully, Can someone tell me how see output through browser like <http://localhost:port/hdfsLocation/>

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

i executed a hadoop mapreduce program successfully in CDH4, but where can i see my output ? , Can someone tell me how to see output through browser like:   It will be helpfull to me

Answer (score 0):

on terminal

```
hadoop dfs -ls /inputfile
```

it will give result like

```
 Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   3 user17 supergroup          0 2014-11-27 16:47 /inputfile/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 user17 supergroup      24441 2014-11-27 16:47 /inputfile/part-00000


hadoop dfs -cat /inputfile/part-00000
```

NameNode and DataNode each run an internal web server in order to display basic information about the current status of the cluster. With the default configuration, the NameNode front page is at `http://namenode-name:50070/`. It lists the DataNodes in the cluster and basic statistics of the cluster. The web interface can also be used to browse the file system (using "Browse the file system" link on the NameNode front page).

if you want see output on web please see. http://gethue.com/#